# Add a set of strings to an existing set with casbah

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I have a user object as follows:

```
{ user: "joe", acks: ["a", "b" ] }
```

I want to add a set of strings to the acks field.  Here's my attempt to do this with one update:

```
def addSomeAcks(toBeAcked = Array[String])
    DB.getCollection("userAcks").update(
        MongoDBObject("user" -> "joe"), 
        $addToSet("acks") $each toBeAcked  
    )
}

def test() {
   addSomeAcks(Set("x", "y", "z"))
}
```

When I run this code I get an embedded set as follows:

```
{ user: "joe", acks: ["a", "b", ["x", "y", "z" ] ] }
```

but the result I want is:

```
{ user: "joe", acks: ["a", "b", "x", "y", "z" ] }
```

I can make it work by calling update for each item in `toBeAcked`, is there a way to do this in one call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `$each` takes a variable number of arguments, not a collection type like `Traversable`. Because of that it treats the set that you pass as a single element and adds it to array as such. This leads to nesting as you observe. You need to unwrap it this way: `$each(toBeAcked: _*)` or pass each elem separately `$each("x", "y", "z")`.

Here is a complete example that works as you'd expect it to:

```
package com.example

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._

object TestApp extends App {

  val col = MongoConnection()("test")("userAcks")

  def printAll(): Unit =
    col.find().foreach(println)

  def insertFirst(): Unit =
    col.insert(MongoDBObject("user" -> "joe", "acks" -> List("a", "b")))

  def addSomeAcks(toBeAcked: Seq[String]): Unit =
    col.update(
      MongoDBObject("user" -> "joe"),
      $addToSet("acks") $each (toBeAcked: _*))

  printAll()
  insertFirst()
  printAll()
  addSomeAcks(Seq("x", "y", "z"))
  printAll()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This make sense. I won't be able to try it until Monday. I'll select your answer then.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I don't recall seeing the notation (x: _*) in Scala. I learned something new.  Thanks.

Comment: To me it seems like an API bug because you would not really want to pass one element to `$each`. You would want to pass a collection. So it would be more clear to change the signature of the `$each` to take a collection instead. Perhaps that's what you anticipated and it happily took your argument as a single element - a bit confusing API in my view. I don't think Scala API for MongoDB has to follow MongoDB syntax exactly. I think this is the case when it should diverge.